# Calling helper method from view Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

how can i call a **helper** method using a button (jquery onClick function) or link_to tag  in Rails 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

`link_to` and its relatives (e.g. `button_to`) call actions on controllers, not helpers.  Sounds like the logic that is in your helper method should be on a controller action, which will `respond_to :js`, allowing you to use jQuery to call that action.

Helper methods are used to allow complex operations or logic to be placed outside of views, to keep views simple.